# Ошибка при запуска бота в Aiogram TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, pycharm

```
    from aiogram import Bot,Dispatcher, executor, types

bot = Bot('TOKEN')
dp = Dispatcher


@dp.message_handler(commands='start')
async def start(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer('Привет')


executor.start_polling(dp)
```

выходит данная ошибка
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\OMEN\PycharmProjects\test\main.py", line 7, in 
@dp.message_handler(commands='text')
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Comment: вы на каждую ошибку будете создавать новую тему? если вы не хотите изучать питон, то хотя бы научитесь переписывать код у источника. И в добавок ко всему ошибку, которую вы прикладываете - не от того кода, который вы указываете в вопросе

Comment: ответ на свой вопрос ищите в комментариях к предыдущему вашему вопросу

Answer (score 0):

```
from aiogram import Bot,Dispatcher, executor, types

bot = Bot('TOKEN')
dp = Dispatcher(bot)


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer('Привет')


executor.start_polling(dp)
```

В Dispatcher нет скобочек